# Failed nested IF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wrote Excel's nested `IF` function to classify timestamp (code shown below). The code failed in some cells and worked in others. The column was formatted appropriately.

[image: photo of the columns]

```
=IF(AND([@TIME]>=TIMEVALUE("5:00:00"), [@TIME]<=TIMEVALUE("11:59:59")), "MORNING BELT", 
 IF(AND(B505>= TIMEVALUE("12:00:00"), B505<=TIMEVALUE("17:59:59")), "AFTERNOON BELT", 
 IF(AND(B505>=TIMEVALUE("18:00:00"), B505<=TIMEVALUE("20:59:59")), "EVENING BELT", 
 IF(AND(B505>=TIMEVALUE("21:00:00"), B505<=TIMEVALUE("23:59:59")), "NIGHT BELT", 
 IF(AND(B505>=TIMEVALUE("00:00:00"), B505<=TIMEVALUE("4:59:59")), "MIDNIGHT BELT","")))))
```

Comment: one thing, you are mixing structured with A1 references, could they be pointing at something different?

Comment: "The column was formatted appropriately" ... formatting doesn't change the underlying value. Is that column a datetime (which is just a number)? (i.e. did you just apply time formatting to a date)? I'd just use `HOUR` here probably.

Comment: @BigBen if there was a date component to the cell, they would all return `""` as they would all be outside the constraints.  My guess is the B505 is not the cell to which it should be pointing and that cell is empty which would make it `0` and which falls in the last constraint and return `"MIDNIGHT BELT"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - oh yeah I missed the `<=` on the last condition...

Comment: The column (the one from which the time column was gotten)  originally contained both date and time. I later separated the time out with INT function. And formatted the time column.

Comment: Gotcha... you could have used `HOUR` on the datetime and skipped the `INT` step. But I think @ScottCraner has identified your problem (mixing `[@TIME]` and `B505`).

Comment: Try:  `=CHOOSE(MATCH(HOUR([@TIME]),{0,5,12,18,21}),"MIDNIGHT BELT","MORNING BELT","AFTERNOON BELT","EVENING BELT","MIDNIGHT BELT")`

Comment: Waoh! your solution worked @ScottCraner. BigBen Thanks for contributing (grateful).  Scott I  will try your code in some other project.